# Save downloaded files in your working directory in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny app below in which I create `.rmd` report and then try to downlaod it. The issue is that when Im not in browser mode the pdf instantly opens when I download it and I do not know where it goes and when I download it while Im in browser mode it is saved in the 'Downloads' folder instead of my working directory. How can I set it to be saved instantly in my working directory?

the ex.rmd

```
---
title: "An example Knitr/R Markdown document"
output: pdf_document
---


{r chunk_name, include=FALSE}
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- 2*x + rnorm(100)
cor(x, y)
```

and the app

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)
library(knitr)
mytitle <- paste0("Life, Death & Statins")
dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  titleWidth = "0px",
  tags$li(a(
    
    
    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("res", "Results"))
    
  ),
  class = "dropdown")
  
  
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dbHeader,
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = "0px",
                               sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar", # id important for updateTabItems
                                           
                                           menuItem("Results", tabName = "res", icon = icon("line-chart"))
                               )           ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
      
      tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}")),
      tabItems(
        
        tabItem("res",
                tags$hr(),
                tags$hr(),
                
                fluidRow(
                  column(3,
                         div(style="display: block; padding: 5px 10px 15px 10px ;",
                             downloadButton("report",
                                            HTML(" PDF"),
                                            style = "fill",
                                            color = "danger",
                                            size = "lg",
                                            block = TRUE,
                                            no_outline = TRUE
                             ) )
                  ),
                  column(6,
                         uiOutput('markdown'))))
      ),
      
      
      
    )
    
  ),
  server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) { 
    hide(selector = "body > div > header > nav > a")
    
    
          output$markdown <- renderUI({
            HTML(markdown::markdownToHTML(knit('ex.rmd', quiet = TRUE)))
          })
          
          
          output$report <- downloadHandler(
            
            filename = "report.pdf",
            content = function(file) {
              src <- normalizePath('ex.Rmd')
              
              # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
              # permission to the current working directory
              owd <- setwd(tempdir())
              on.exit(setwd(owd))
              file.copy(src, 'ex.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)
              
              library(rmarkdown)
              out <- render(input = 'ex.Rmd', 
                            output_format = pdf_document(), 
                            params = list(data = data)
              )
              file.rename(out, file)
              
            }
          )
        
  }
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not understood exactly what you need so I propose two answers depending of what you need

1. You can't make a **client** browser download "instantly" into a folder without any popup. If that was the case any website would deal with your hard drive openly. Though, you can sepecify the "save to" menu instead of the pdf reader using `contentType="application/octet-stream"` as an arg of downloadHandler
2. You can render your pdf anywhere you want **server side** with the `output_file` arg of render.

Comment: Ιf you run the code above in browser mode and try to save the file it is saved in downloads folder by default and not in the rsudio working directory. How can I save the file in folder of my choice? I get no pop up

Comment: As i told, server side you can use the output_file arg of render, and client side the contentType arg of downloadHandler

Comment: can you give a working example of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `output_file` when you define `output_dir`.  Please try this

```
 output$report <- downloadHandler(

            filename = "report.pdf",
            content = function(file) {
              src <- normalizePath('ex.Rmd')
              
              owd <- setwd(tempdir())
              on.exit(setwd(owd))
              file.copy(src, 'ex.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)

              library(rmarkdown)
              out <- render(input = 'ex.Rmd',
                            output_format = pdf_document(),
                            output_file = "reportt.pdf",
                            #output_dir = "C://My Disk Space//temp//",
                            output_dir = "C://Users//User//Documents//Hodgkins//www//",
                            params = list(data = data)
              )
              #file.rename(out, file)
              file.copy(out, file)
            }
```